# Unbind events added by an external script loaded with jQuery's getScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading an external script using jQuery's $.getScript function and it has something in it which I cannot understand:

```
if (!!window.addEventListener){ // FF
    window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
} else if (!!window.attachEvent){ // IE
    window.attachEvent('onload', init);
} else {
    window.onclick = init;
}
```

Can someone please explain what this does?

I'm not sure but it adds some event listeners to check that the page is loaded.

But since I am loading the script with $.getScript function, I don't need those listeners anymore.

Is there a way to unbind them in the callback of the $.getScript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addEventListener` adds event handlers, and `attachEvent` does the same for browsers that doesn't support `addEventListener`, which is just older IE.

The condition you have checks which one is available, and attaches an event handler to the window.onload event that calls the function `init()`.
If none of the regular onload handler are available, it falls back to calling the `init()` function once the window is first clicked.

To remove the function, you'll have to try and do the opposite once the script has loaded.

You say you're using `$.getScript`, and that has a callback, so something like :

```
$.getScript('myscript.js', function() {
    if (window.removeEventListener) {
        window.removeEventListener( 'load', init, false );
    }else if ( window.detachEvent ) {
        window.detachEvent( 'onload', init );
    }else{
        window.onclick = function() {};
    }
});
```

of course, it would be much easier and better to just remove the original event handler in the script you're loading if you no longer need that event handler.